# Passing a Rails Variable into a Controller Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I've got a program that I've been working on for a while that is just a basic barcode scanning system.

My controller for a raw good is as below:

```
class RawsController < ApplicationController
  def new
        @raw = Raw.new
  end

        def create
        @raw = Raw.new(params[raw_params])
        if @raw.save
            receive(@raw)
            redirect_to new_raw_path
        end     
    end

  def receive(raw)
        scanned = Raw.find_by(code: raw.code)
        if scanned.quantity.nil?
            flash[:danger] = "no match"
        else
            scanned.quantity += 1
            if scanned.save
                respond_to do |format|
                    format.html {}
                    format.json{}
                end
            end
        end
  end
private
    def raw_params
        params.require(:raw).permit(:code, :product, :quantity)
    end

end
```

Now, what I want to happen, is that when someone enters a barcode number into a form, it creates @raw as an instance of the Raw(for raw goods) class.  Then in the receive function, it searches for a matching product in my inventory and then adds one unit to my raw goods inventory.

However once I get to the `scanned.quantity += 1` line, I continually get an error that this method is undefined for nil class.

I added in the `scanned.quantity.nil?` line, and I do get that flash message, so I know the problem has to do with the quantity being nil.  But, I'm not sure how to fix this.

Any help?

Comment: How are you getting to receive in the case that `scanned` is nil?

Comment: It's not that the `quantity` is `nil`, but the `scanned` is `nil`. To help you understand the error message better, `quantity` is the method that you're trying to access from `scanned` which equals `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your initialisation at `Raw.new(...)`

Looking at the data you posted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38591622/passing-a-rails-variable-into-a-controller-method/38591803?noredirect=1#comment64573373_38591803), I could say that the action is not creating the `Raw` object with correct attributes. You need to use the permitted attributes when you want to save. You are calling `new` with `params[raw_params]` which will be `nil`. It should be `Raw.new(raw_params)`

Change:

```
  def create
    @raw = Raw.new(raw_params)
    if @raw.save
        receive(@raw)
        redirect_to new_raw_path
    end
  end
```

Comment: Yes!  Thank you so much.  I had initially designed this program without realizing I would need to account for strong parameters.  A simple problem caused by poor syntax.  Never would've realized that. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since your if clause with `scanned.quantity.nil?` succeeds, it means that `scanned` object is present however `quantity` is `nil`. I assume you didn't have a default value of `0` on it.

Ideally, I would add a default value of `0` to the `quantity` column within the migration that added that column to the Database.

However, you could set it to `0` before performing the increment. Also, you needn't really do `find_by` again since you already pass the `Raw` object. The actions can be performed on that object itself.

```
def receive(raw)
    scanned = raw

    if scanned.nil?
      # your flash message
    else
      scanned.quantity ||= 0
      scanned.quantity += 1
      if scanned.save
         respond_to do |format|
             format.html {}
             format.json{}
         end
       end
     end
end
```

Comment: The confusion for me is that I seeded in some test variables in the migration, so quantity is not nil.

Comment: can to paste the result of `puts @raw.attributes` before the call `receive(@raw)` ?

Comment: Also, you needn't really do the `find_by` in the `receive` method as you already pass the object that you are fetching. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: The puts is {"id"=>538, "code"=>nil, "product"=>nil, "quantity"=>nil, "created_at"=>Tue, 26 Jul 2016 14:26:06 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Tue, 26 Jul 2016 14:26:06 UTC +00:00}

Comment: @Mascasc You totally are looking at wrong place! See my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying `+=` on a `nil` value that's why you are getting that error.

When you are creating new instance @raw the value `@raw.quantity` is `nil`

Use `after_initialize` to set quantity to 0

```
class Raw
  after_initialize :set_quantity

  def set_quantity
    self.quantity = 0
  end
end
```

**Or**

Write a migration to change quantity default value to 0

```
def change
  change_column :raw, :quantity, :integer, default: 0
end
```

Comment: I'm still getting no match, which I think means that my variable "scanned" is not being found.

Comment: It cannot be `nil` as far as I think. You save the `@raw` and then pass it in and you `find_by` on `Raw` with the same `code`. It should be present.

Comment: got it your quantity is nil

Comment: Updated my answer according to your scnario